# Scrollable text not depending on text length

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextpane, scrollable

I'm creating a GUI with a sidebar which has constant width, I want to add a Scrollable text, being the text into a JTextPane, all this into a JPanel PanelList.

Problem is that it will automatically adjust to the length of the longest string so the scrollable is always showing the whole text - that's not what I'm looking for.

Having this code:

```
public PanelList(int size){

        text = new JTextPane();
        text.setEditable(false);
        text.setText("IwantthisStringtobeScrollable\n" +
                "ThisStringis30characterslength");
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(text);
        scrollpane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollpane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        this.add(scrollpane);

}
```

What method do I have to invoke so as to show only 20 chars of the JTextPane and be able to scroll?

EDIT: The width to be shown by the scrollpanel is that of the param size.

Comment: You don't want the scroll bars to appear ? or do you want them ?

Comment: i do want the scrollbars

Comment: I think you need `JTextPane` to the view port of the scroll pane

Comment: What would be de code for it?
Also, the JScrollPane constructor isn't supposed to set the referred param as the viewport?

Comment: You can try [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewportView%28java.awt.Component%29)

Comment: That's kind of the same of what constructor method does, and doesn't apply any size restriction.

Comment: Do you want *both* scrollbars? If not, you can set the horizontal scroll bar policy to `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER`, then your side bar will scroll downwards and the text is more likely to wrap correctly.

Comment: I'm just specifying both "scroll as needed" to be formal, but it is not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What method do I have to invoke so as to show only 20 chars of the JTextPane

A `JTextPane` doesn't support this concept.

If you are only displaying simple text (and don't need multiple fonts or text color) then you can use a `JTextArea`. Then you would do something like:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
```

This will create a text area that contains 5 rows and 20 columns. The columns is not exact because the width of every character is different. If you want exactly 20 characters then you would need to use a monospaced font.

Comment: Thanks, JTextArea solved my problem, I didn't know its contructor allowed to set, somehow, the size of the scrollable viewport. Thank you so much.